# Hidraw doesn't find device without device-specific kernel driver being loaded

Tags: linux, hid, rust

I'm trying to make a userspace Linux program that talks to a Bluetooth HID device, specifically the [Wii remote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote).

When the `hid-wiimote` kernel module is loaded, I can use the [hidapi](https://crates.io/crates/hidapi) library (with the `linux-static-hidraw` backend) to talk to the device directly, but the kernel driver does periodic polling and changes the operation mode often. When I blacklist the module in `/etc/modprobe.d`, the LEDs on the controller flash forever and the library returns this error:

> No HID devices with requested VID/PID found in the system.

I'm pretty sure I've set up the `udev` permissions properly, here's my custom rule file:

```
KERNEL=="hidraw*", KERNELS=="0005:057E:*.*", MODE="0666"
```

For reference, here's my minimal Rust example:

```rs
/**
 * [dependencies]
 * hidapi = { version = "2.4.0", default-features = false, features = ["linux-static-hidraw"] }
 */

use hidapi::HidApi;

fn main() {
    let hid = HidApi::new().unwrap();
    let wiimote = hid.open(0x057e, 0x0306).unwrap(); // error if `hid-wiimote` isn't loaded
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I've been trying to use the wrong API. While it's possible to communicate with the Wii Remote via Hidraw when the `hid_wiimote` kernel module is loaded, its native communication method is [Bluetooth L2CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_protocols#Logical_link_control_and_adaptation_protocol_(L2CAP)), as the [WiiBrew page](https://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote#HID_Interface) says.